# Python - Pre-declaring optionally used object?

Tags: python

I have some Pickled Python objects that I intend to use conditionally. Code looks like:

```
if(mode == 1):
    scaler = joblib.load('all_scaler.pkl')
#Do stuff, create input variable
if(mode == 1):
    scaledinput = scaler.transform(input)
```

If I use it like this, of course I get the error `variable used before assignment`. If I do this however:

```
scaler = []
if(mode == 1):
    scaler = joblib.load('all_scaler.pkl')
#Do stuff, create input variable
if(mode == 1):
    scaledinput = scaler.transform(input)
```

I get the error, that `list object has no function called transform`. I thought Python would dynamically assign the object type, but doesn't seem so... How can I so this properly?

Comment: Are those actual errors, or just warnings from a linter? Why don't you move the use of scaler inside the scope where it's actually available? Also note that the parentheses around the conditions are redundant (and unidiomatic) in Python.

Comment: Python will change the type when you assign a new value. What do you want to happen if mode isn't 1, but modeling is 2?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because the code is more complicated that that, and would mean I'd have to copy a for loop into 4 different places.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actual errors: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'transform'`

Comment: @jonrsharpe The if-else logic is not the issue here, I've got that figured out, this is just a simplificationthat shows what my issue is, bit not how I handle each individual case.

Comment: Don't declare `scaler = []` - it's incorrect. Correct is to design your code so `scaler` is only used when it was loaded. And "list has no attribute transform" exception means that somehow, your `scaler.transform` was called without `scaler = joblib.load(...)`.

Comment: If you want to use `scaler.transform()`, then you have to have run `scaler = joblib.load()` first.  Your logic is broken if you can't guarantee that.

Comment: But that's the point: I only want to use the scaler CONDITIONALLY.

Comment: More pythonic is `scaler = None`. However the issue Ned is explaining is that you have `if mode == 1` for both cases, however somehow in your code the first `if` wasn't executed which is why you get the error. So either your actual if conditions don't match or in between you are changing `mode`.

Comment: But the `mode` is never changed and these ARE the actual conditions... :/